# Piping to a stream that needs to be both readable and writable

Tags: node.js, stream

I'd like to be able to pipe from the `src` stream to the `something` stream. I understand that `something` needs to be a writable stream, as it's being piped to, however, it needs to also be a readable stream, so that it can pipe to `somethingElse'. What should`something` return in order to make this work?

```
example.task('taskOne', function() {
  return example
    .src('pathName')
    .pipe(something())
    .pipe(somethingElse())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Made use of node modules `through2` which solves this exact issue.